# Is it possible to do this? Write a fraction as a product

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I have two quantities $A$ and $B$ and I consider the fraction
$$\frac{1}{A+B}$$
I would like to write the above expression as a Product, i.e. find functions $F$ and $G$ such that
$$\frac{1}{A+B} = F(A)G(B)$$
for any functions F and G I don't even need them to be explicit, I just need to know if that is possible :)
Thank you very much!

Comment: But it isn't possible.

Comment: Why would you think that was possible? It shouldn't be hard to prove it is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G(1)F(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ so  we see that $F(x)=\frac{1}{G(1)(x+1)}$ and similarly $G(x)=\frac{1}{F(1)(x+1)}$. Then $$F(A)G(B) = \frac{1}{F(1)G(1)} \frac{1}{(1+A)(1+B)}$$

$F(1)G(1)=\frac{1}{2}$, so this means:

$$\frac{1}{A+B}=F(A)G(B) = \frac{2}{(1+A)(1+B)}$$

or $$(1+A)(1+B)=2(A+B)$$

That means that $1+AB=A+B$ for all $A,B$, or $(A-1)(B-1)=0$. But this is only equal when $A=1$ or $B=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this were the case.  Then, for any fixed $B$, we let $A\to \infty$.  The fraction approaches zero, so $F(A)\to 0$.  This is also true if $A\to \infty$.  Hence $\lim_{A\to\pm \infty}F(A)=0$, and by symmetry $\lim_{B\to \pm \infty}F(B)=0$.

However, we now let $A,B$ get large not independently.  Set $B=-A+1$, and let $A\to \infty$.  Now $B\to -\infty$, so $F(A)G(B)\to 0$ and yet the fraction is always $1$.